# Cygwin Console dumping massive cryptic output then typing 1;2;6;22c

Tags: c++, cygwin

I'm writing a lexer in C++ and I was able to compile the program and link it just fine; however when it comes to running it, I get a massive output dump, and I don't know why it's happening or if it's even related to the program I wrote. It's I cant even copy the entire dump but here is a [gif](https://gyazo.com/dee5154b3b6a85ecd082246bd45218b7) of it happening. 
Here is the program just for good measure.

I have compiling and running with cygwin on windows 10.

> token.h

```
#ifndef TOKEN_H
#define TOKEN_H

#include <string>

class ice_lexer;

enum ice_type_enum {
    ICE_NONE,
    ICE_EOF,
    ICE_MODULE,
    ICE_IDENT,
    ICE_FLT,
    ICE_NUM,
    ICE_STR,
    // SYMBOLS
    ICE_RPARA,
    ICE_LPARA,
    ICE_RBRAC,
    ICE_LBRAC,
    ICE_RCURL,
    ICE_LCURL,
    ICE_PERIOD,
    ICE_COLON,
    ICE_SEMIC,
    ICE_COMMA,
    // COMPARISON
    ICE_EQLTO,
    ICE_NOTEQL,
    ICE_GRT,
    ICE_GRTEQL,
    ICE_LES,
    ICE_LESEQL,
    // ASSIGNMENT
    ICE_EQL,
    ICE_ADDEQL,
    ICE_SUBEQL,
    ICE_MULEQL,
    ICE_DIVEQL,
    ICE_CAREQL,
    // URNARY
    ICE_URNARYNOT,
    ICE_URNARYSUB,
    // BINARY
    ICE_ADD,
    ICE_SUB,
    ICE_MUL,
    ICE_DIV,
    ICE_MOD,
    ICE_CAR,
    ICE_CAT,
    // TERNARY
    ICE_TERNARY,
    // KEYWORDS
    ICE_IMPORT,
    ICE_AS,
    ICE_WHILE,
    ICE_FOR,
    ICE_BREAK,
    ICE_IF,
    ICE_RETURN,
    ICE_TRUE,
    ICE_FALSE,
    // TYPES
    ICE_TYPEDEF,
    ICE_CLASS,
    ICE_ENUM,
    ICE_INT,
    ICE_FLOAT,
    ICE_STRING,
    ICE_BOOLEAN,
    ICE_VOID,
    ICE_STRUCT
};

typedef struct ice_keyword {
    std::string word;
    ice_type_enum type;
} ice_keyword;

class ice_type {
public:
    std::string string;
    ice_type_enum type;
    ice_type(ice_type_enum t);
};

class ice_token {
public:
    ice_type type;
    size_t line;
    size_t pos;

    std::string str;
    double flt;
    size_t num;

    ice_token(const ice_lexer* lexer, ice_type_enum t);
    ~ice_token() {};
    void print();
};

#endif
```

> token.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "token.h"
#include "lexer.h"

static const std::string ice_type_enum_strings[] = {
    // ABSTRACT
    "no type",
    "end of file",
    "module",
    "identifier",
    "floating",
    "number",
    "string",
    // SYMBOLS
    "left para",
    "right para",
    "left brac",
    "right brac",
    "left curl",
    "right curl",
    "period",
    "colon",
    "semi",
    "comma",
    // COMPARISON
    "eql to",
    "not eql",
    "grt",
    "grt eql",
    "les",
    "les eql",
    // ASSIGNMENT
    "eql",
    "add eql",
    "sub eql",
    "mul eql",
    "div eql",
    "car eql",
    // URNARY
    "urnarynot",
    "urnarysub",
    // BINARY
    "add",
    "sub",
    "mul",
    "div",
    "mod",
    "car",
    "cat",
    // TERNARY
    "ternary",
    // KEYWORDS
    "import",
    "as",
    "while",
    "for",
    "break",
    "if",
    "return",
    "true",
    "false",
    // TYPES
    "typedef",
    "class",
    "enum",
    "int",
    "float",
    "string",
    "bool",
    "void",
    "struct"
};

ice_type::ice_type(ice_type_enum t) {
    string = ice_type_enum_strings[t];
    type = t;
}

ice_token::ice_token(const ice_lexer* lexer, ice_type_enum t):type(t) {
    line = lexer->line;
    pos = lexer->pos;
    num = 0;
}

void ice_token::print() {
    std::cout << "TYPE [ STR: \'" << this->type.string << "\' | ENUM: " << this->type.type << " ]:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\tLINE NO. " << this->line << " IN THE " << this->pos << "TH ROW" << std::endl;

    if (this->type.type == ICE_NUM)
        std::cout << "\tNUMBER VALUE: \'" << this->num << "\'" << std::endl;

    if (this->type.type == ICE_FLT)
        std::cout << "\tFLOAT VALUE: \'" << this->flt << "\'" << std::endl;

    if (this->type.type != ICE_NUM && this->type.type != ICE_FLT)
        std::cout << "\tSTR VALUE: \'" << this->str << "\'" << std::endl;
}
```

> lexer.h

```
#ifndef LEXER_H
#define LEXER_H

#include "token.h"
#include <string>

class ice_token;

#define newline() {     \
    this->line++;       \
    this->pos = 0;      \
}

class ice_lexer {
public:
    std::string source;
    size_t length;
    size_t line;
    size_t pos;
    size_t ptr;
    ice_lexer(std::string file_name);
    ~ice_lexer() {};
    ice_token lexer_next();
private:
    const char look(int offset);
    const char advance(int offset);
    void comment(void);
    void nested(void);
    ice_token symbol(ice_type_enum type, std::string string, int move);
    void ident(void);
};

#endif
```

> lexer.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <assert.h>
#include "token.h"
#include "lexer.h"

extern const ice_keyword keywords[] = {
    {"import", ICE_IMPORT},
    {"as", ICE_AS},
    {"while", ICE_WHILE},
    {"for", ICE_FOR},
    {"break", ICE_BREAK},
    {"if", ICE_IF},
    {"return", ICE_RETURN},
    {"true", ICE_TRUE},
    {"false", ICE_FALSE},
    {"typedef", ICE_TYPEDEF},
    {"class", ICE_CLASS},
    {"enum", ICE_ENUM},
    {"int", ICE_INT},
    {"float", ICE_FLOAT},
    {"string", ICE_STRING},
    {"bool", ICE_BOOLEAN},
    {"void", ICE_VOID},
    {"struct", ICE_STRUCT}
};

ice_lexer::ice_lexer(std::string file_name) {
    std::ifstream input_file(file_name);
    std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input_file)),
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    line = 1;
    pos = 0;
    ptr = 0;
}

const char ice_lexer::look(int offset = 0) {
    if (this->ptr + offset < this->length)
        return '\0';
    return this->source[this->ptr + offset];
}

const char ice_lexer::advance(int offset) {
    assert(this->ptr + offset < this->length);
    return look();
}

void ice_lexer::comment(void) {
    while (look() != '\n') { advance(1); }
    newline();
}

void ice_lexer::nested(void) {
    size_t depth = 1;

    while (depth > 0) {
        if (look(0) == '\\' && look(1) == '\\') {
            advance(2);
            depth--;
        } else if (look(0) == '/' && look(1) == '/') {
            advance(2);
            depth++;
        } else {
            advance(1);
        }
    }
}

ice_token ice_lexer::symbol(ice_type_enum type, std::string string, int move) {
    ice_token token(this, type);
    token.str = string;
    advance(move);

    return token;
}

ice_token ice_lexer::lexer_next() {
    /*
    while (look() != '\0') {
        switch (look()) {
        case '+':
            if (look(1) == '=')
                return symbol(ICE_ADDEQL, "+=", 2);
            else
                return symbol(ICE_ADD, "+", 1);
            break;
        case '-':
            if (look(1) == '=')
                return symbol(ICE_ADDEQL, "+=", 2);
            else
                return symbol(ICE_SUB, "-", 1);
            break;
        case '*':
            if (look(1) == '=')
                return symbol(ICE_ADDEQL, "+=", 2);
            else
                return symbol(ICE_MUL, "*", 1);
            break;
        case '/':
            if (look(1) == '=')
                return symbol(ICE_DIVEQL, "/=", 2);
            else if(look(1) == '/')
                nested();
            else
                return symbol(ICE_DIV, "/", 1);
            break;
        case '^':
            if (look(1) == '=')
                return symbol(ICE_CAREQL, "^=", 2);
            else
                return symbol(ICE_CAR, "^", 1);
            break;
        case '~':
            comment();
        case '(':
            return symbol(ICE_LPARA, "(", 1);
            break;
        case ')':
            return symbol(ICE_RPARA, ")", 1);
            break;
        case '[':
            return symbol(ICE_LBRAC, "[", 1);
            break;
        case ']':
            return symbol(ICE_RBRAC, "]", 1);
            break;
        case '{':
            return symbol(ICE_LCURL, "{", 1);
            break;
        case '}':
            return symbol(ICE_RCURL, "}", 1);
            break;
        default:

            break;
        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: To eliminate confusion... Is there a better name for ice_type::string?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure their is :). So it turns out it is code related, seems like accessing a member of an ice_lexer type causes this output.

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple of changes and kinda got it working. Some of the stuff you're doing is a bit wonky.

```
ice_lexer::ice_lexer(std::string file_name) {
    std::ifstream input_file(file_name);
    std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input_file)),
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    line = 1;
    pos = 0;
    ptr = 0;
}
```

You're reading the file into `content`, which is a local variable. You probably meant to read it into `source`. You're also not updating `length`, which I guess should be `source.size()`.

There's a bug in `ice_lexer::look()`:

```
const char ice_lexer::look(int offset = 0) {
    if (this->ptr + offset < this->length)
        return '\0';
    return this->source[this->ptr + offset];
}
```

The condition should be `>=`, not `<`. Another similar bug in `ice_lexer::advance()`:

```
const char ice_lexer::advance(int offset) {
    assert(this->ptr + offset < this->length);
    return look();
}
```

should be `<=`.

When you see garbage on the console, it usually means that you're printing a string that doesn't have a `\0` at the end, and it's just running away in memory until it finds a `\0` somewhere. It might also crash if you're reading somewhere you're not supposed to. This in turn probably means that you have uninitialized variables.

Learn to use your debugger properly. This was pretty easy to figure out by stepping through functions and looking at variables.